# how to make outlook run rules on every midnight

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office

I have a specific rules on Outlook client. How to make it run on every midnight (instead of running whenever an email is received).

Answer (score 0):

depend of your rule, you could use Flow who can execute action at specifique time. If you know code, you could also use Azure Function.